# Voice activated bluetooth recorder

Tags: applications, bluetooth, voice-recognition, video-recording

Apps like [Babbler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.itadapter.android.games.aar&hl=en_GB) and [Automatic audio recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.itadapter.android.games.aar&hl=en_GB) are noise activated, but none I've found are Bluetooth compatible. Do you know any? Is there a way to make them recognize the Bluetooth recorder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autovoice and autoinput can provide voice-activated functionality for a bluetooth recording app, though you will be fiddling with setting it up like a pianist.